# Should I save GraphViewSeries to savedInstanceState?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I'm building a history chart in my app using the GraphView library from jjoe64. My question is do I need to manually save the GraphViewSeries to savedInstanceState or it will be automatically preserved because it's part of a Graph View?

Also in general I'm wondering what fields will be automatically saved when the app is destroyed? If android preserved the state of all views by itself, does it mean it will also preserve any data used by the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GraphView I can say, that you have to save the state for yourself and restore it